# Scale down Kubernetes pods to 0 replica until traffic on site

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have setup a standard Kubernetes cluster which includes ReplicaSets, Deployments, Pods etc ... I am looking to save costings around this as it is just constantly running and it is a Pre Production environment.

I was wondering if there is a feature in Kubernetes to say that if a Pod has not been used in the last 60 minutes, it shuts down. If then someone requests to use that pod it will spin back up. I understand the request might take longer as the Pod will need to spin up, but the cost saved for the pre-production environment would be huge.

I have been trying to look around, but the only resource I could find for this was https://codeberg.org/hjacobs/kube-downscaler. Looking at this, it only allows you to specify times for shut down not traffic.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Did you look into kubernetes `kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler` with custom metrics?

Comment: @Bimal I did, but does that allow pods to scale down to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Since `kubernetes 1.16` there is a feature gate called [`HPAScaleToZero`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) which enables setting `minReplicas` to 0 for `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` resources when using custom or external metrics. It has to be explicitly enabled as it's disabled by default.

Additionally you can use KEDA for event-driven autoscaling. It enables you to scale down deployment to 0. It uses [`ScaledObject`](https://keda.sh/docs/1.4/concepts/scaling-deployments/#scaledobject-spec) custom resource definition which is used to define how KEDA should scale your application and what the triggers are.

Other approach might be to use a custom solution called [`Zero Pod Autoscaler`](https://github.com/greenkeytech/zero-pod-autoscaler) which:

> can scale the Deployment all the way down to zero replicas when it is
> not in use. It can work alongside an HPA: when scaled to zero, the HPA
> ignores the Deployment; once scaled back to one, the HPA may scale up
> further.

Comment: Please note that the HPAScaleToZero feature gate is still in alpha (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/)), which means it is not supported by some managed K8S providers.

Comment: If you cannot enable the featuer gate and want to use the built in HPA, check out https://github.com/machine424/kube-hpa-scale-to-zero